# How to schedule a command in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, reload

I have a pod named 'sample_pod' and a container named 'sample_container' running inside the pod.

I need to run a specific command to run inside container every 1hr. Is there any specific command can run/schedule for every one hour inside sample_container?

If so, how can I schedule to run that command inside container every one hour? Or is there a  kubernetes native approach to achieve this?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not the best practice with containers. One should not care about keeping a container absolutely up, in contrary.  https://www.hava.io/blog/cattle-vs-pets-devops-explained.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, just do not use containers but use instead classical server with a cron task. (cf. my comment under your question)

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes cronjob feature should be able to do the needful for your requirement. Have a look at this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)